# How do I replace the background-1.xml file under /usr/share/backgrounds/contest/?

Tags: 11.10, customization, desktop-background, slideshow

Help with the `background-1.xml` file under `/usr/share/backgrounds/contest/`.

I screwed my .xml file... and the dumb here that is writing right now, didn't keep a safe copy of the original file/code...

Would somebody send me the original code from the Oneiric 11.10 version, or the .xml file itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/usr/share/backgrounds/contest/background-1.xml` file can be reinstalled by  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-wallpapers`

Comment: Thank you very much.... I was looking in Google about 3hours and no one gave a cool and practical answer... I'll try it right now.

Comment: So.... my wallpapers now are duplicated... but i think its all right. LOL

Comment: So... I used the follow steps to solve the question.

sudo nautilus
deleted the file /usr/share/gnome-background-properties/ubuntu-wallpapers.xml

Now its OK